# Creating a variable in Python and assigning it to the last call of a function without calling the function again

Tags: python, python-3.x

so I'm creating a very simple Temperature class that can convert a given temperature from Celsius to Fahrenheit and vice versa. The problem is that I want to have a "convert" method within the class that executes if called directly but not if being assigned to a variable. Here's my code:

```
class Temperature:
    def __init__(self,temp=None,cf='C'):
        if temp == None:
            self.temp = float('0.0')
        else:
            try:
                self.temp = float("{0:.2f}".format(temp))
            except:
                print('Your temperature must be a number!')              
        if cf not in ['c','C','f','F']:
            print('You must identify the temperature as either F for Fahrenheit or C for Celsius!')
        else:
            self.cf = cf.upper()
    def convert(self):
        if self.cf == 'F':
            self.temp = float("{0:.2f}".format((self.temp - 32) * 5 / 9))
            self.cf = 'C'
            return(self)
        elif self.cf == 'C':
            self.temp = float("{0:.2f}".format((9/5)*self.temp + 32))
            self.cf = 'F'
            return(self)
    def __repr__(self):           
        return('Temperature({},{})'.format(self.temp,self.cf))
```

Results:

```
>>>t1 = Temperature()
>>>t1
Temperature(0.0,C)
>>>t2 = Temperature(100,'f')
>>>t2
Temperature(100.0,F)
>>>t3 = t3 = Temperature('12.5','c')
>>>t3
Temperature(12.5,C) #works fine up to here

>>>t1.convert()
Temperature(32.0,C) #converts when called - just what I want
>>>t4 = t1.convert() #Should set t4 equal TO VALUE of 't1.convert()' without rerunning method
>>>t4
Temperature(0.0,C) #THIS IS WHERE I GET LOST. I want t4 to print out 'Temperature(32.0,C)' Ideas?
```

Comment: There is no way for a method to know whether its return value is being assigned to a result or not.  You could have `convert` store its last return value and return it again next time, but there's no way to tell it to only do this if its result wasn't assigned to a variable.  Why don't you just assign the result to a variable when you call the method the first time?

Comment: I think you meant `Temperature(0.0, *F*)` in your example. Also, it's not clear why you expect a call to `convert()` to NOT convert; that is violating the _principle of least astonishment_ for the API of this class. Why not keep it as is? `convert()` converts the object and also returns itself, so that you can chain calls.

Comment: you should reconsider your approach e.g., instead of the `convert()` method with an unclear return value, you could define `C`, `F` properties that return CelsiusTemperature or FahrenheitTemperature correspondingly (that also have `C` and `F` properties).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach is to create new instance of `Temperature` and assign to it converted values without modifying values of current instance of `Temperature`:

```
    def convert(self):
        if self.cf == 'F':
            return Temperature(float("{0:.2f}".format((self.temp - 32) * 5 / 9)), 'C')
        elif self.cf == 'C':
            return Temperature(float("{0:.2f}".format((9/5)*self.temp + 32)))
```

Result:

```
>>>t1 = Temperature()
>>>t1
Temperature(0.0,C)
>>>t1.convert()
Temperature(32.0,C)
>>>t1
Temperature(0.0,C)
>>>t4 = t1.convert()
>>>t4
Temperature(32.0,C)
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider this, when you are calling `t1.convert()` again it changes `self.cf` value,
so it run **if** condition next time and return Instance.

```
t1 = Temperature()

print t1.convert()
print '======='
print t1.convert()
print '======='
t4 = t1.convert()
print t4
```

output:-

```
C
Temperature(32.0,F)
=======
F
Temperature(0.0,C)
=======
C
Temperature(32.0,F)
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could do something like this?

```
class TemperatureError(Exception):
    pass


class Temperature(object):
    def __init__(self, temp=None, scale='C'):
        self._celcius = None
        self._fahrenheit = None
        if temp:
            if scale in ('c', 'C'):
                self.celcius = temp
            elif scale in ('f', 'F'):
                self.fahrenheit = temp
            else:
                raise TemperatureError

    @property
    def celcius(self):
        return self._celcius

    @celcius.setter
    def celcius(self, temp):
        self._celcius = float('{0:.2f}'.format(temp))
        self._fahrenheit = float('{0:.2f}'.format((temp - 32) * 5 / 9))

    @property
    def fahrenheit(self):
        return self._fahrenheit

    @fahrenheit.setter
    def fahrenheit(self, temp):
        self._celcius = float('{0:.2f}'.format(temp * 9 / 5 + 32))
        self._fahrenheit = float('{0:.2f}'.format(temp))
```

The result would be something like:

```
>>> t = Temperature(20, 'F')
>>> t.fahrenheit
20.0
>>> t.celcius
68.0
```